# IndexOutOfBoundException for ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

**My Code**

```
public List<GeoPoint> compute_polygon(List<GeoPoint> waypoints, double d)
        {
            int N = waypoints.size();//25
            int T = 2 * N - 1;//49
//          GeoPoint[] reduced_waypoints = waypoints.toArray(new GeoPoint[waypoints.size()]);
            List<GeoPoint> polygon =  new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(T);
            for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
            {

                GeoPoint M = get_disp(waypoints.get(i - 1), waypoints.get(i), waypoints.get(i + 1), d);
                polygon.add(i, v_add(waypoints.get(i), M));// here it fails and throws exception. 
                polygon.add(T-i, v_sub(waypoints.get(i), M));
            }
}
```

**Error Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:444)
    at de.carbook.vendor.search.PathPolygon.compute_polygon(PathPolygon.java:40)
    at de.carbook.vendor.search.Cleansing_the_waypoints.main(Cleansing_the_waypoints.java:41)
```

I am not able to figure out whats causing the problem.

the error is at `polygon.add(i, v_add(waypoints.get(i), M));`here it fails and throws exception.

I tried `polygon.add(index,element)` and `polygon.set(index,element)` it fails on both cases

While debugging i found this line `List<GeoPoint> polygon =  new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(T);` is initiallized to null (Empty). Is it a problem?

**Update 1**

```
public List<GeoPoint> compute_polygon(List<GeoPoint> points, double d)
        {
            int N = points.size();//25
            int T = 2 * N - 1;//49
            GeoPoint[] waypoints = points.toArray(new GeoPoint[N]);
            GeoPoint[] polygon = new GeoPoint[T];
            for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
            {
                GeoPoint M = get_disp(waypoints[i - 1], waypoints[i], waypoints[i + 1], d);
                polygon[i]     = v_add(waypoints[i], M); 
                polygon[T - i] = v_sub(waypoints[i], M);
            }
            GeoPoint A = v_mul(v_nor(v_prp(v_sub(waypoints[1], waypoints[0]))), d);
            GeoPoint B = v_mul(v_nor(v_prp(v_sub(waypoints[N-1], waypoints[N-2]))), d);
            polygon[0] = v_add(waypoints[0], A); polygon[T] = v_sub(waypoints[0], A);
            polygon[N - 1] = v_add(waypoints[N-1], B); polygon[N] = v_sub(waypoints[N-1], B);

            List<GeoPoint> poly =  new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(Arrays.asList(polygon));
            System.out.println(poly);

            return poly;
        }
```

**Error for update**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49
    at de.carbook.vendor.search.PathPolygon.compute_polygon(PathPolygon.java:67)
    at de.carbook.vendor.search.Cleansing_the_waypoints.main(Cleansing_the_waypoints.java:41)
```

Comment: use  `polygon.add( v_add(waypoints.get(i), M))` instead of `polygon.add(i, v_add(waypoints.get(i), M))`

Comment: @Jens but I need those index to place points in an order.

Comment: But you add it in the same order with both Statements.

Comment: Start your loop from `i=0` instead of 1.

Comment: @zombie That's a matter of taste and won't help to solve the problem.

Comment: @zombie It didnt solve my problem

Comment: List<GeoPoint> waypoints, is empty. What is the value for the N and dont add element by index .

Comment: @Loga valuue for `N` is `45`. Thing is I need to place the result in order that is above.

Comment: Add at index does not work the way you obviously think it does: "Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. **Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).**" From [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)). Now in the beginning the size of your list is 0 and you try to insert at index 1, which means there would have to be an element at index one (or 1 to be the size) and thus 1 Element already present.

Comment: After Edit: `polygon[T]` -> Size is T , so your max allowed index is T-1.

Comment: @Fildor Yes you are write. when i did `polygon[T+1]` i got the resut.

Comment: It is the only place you are using T so I guess you better make `int T = 2 * N - 1;` to be `int T = 2 * N ;` Less confusing.

Comment: @Fildor Yea I made myself confuse. But what would be the case if i were to use ArrayList will your suggestion works?

Comment: No that's the point in using array instead. Adding to an ArrayList at index n will shift all subsequent entries to the right. Example: you have [0,1,2,3] -> Size 4. Now you add "5" at index 2. Result would be: [0,1,5,2,3] -> Size = 5. So what you added before at index 3 will then be at index 4 breaking your algorithm.

Comment: @Fildor So using array in my case is lot better  because i want to add it specific index

Comment: Exactly, yes. I use following rule of thumb: You know the size (and size will not change dynamically) and want to access (get/set) at specific index: use array. If not: look for better suited datastructure or interface.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks a lot for enlightening me!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to insert at a particular index whereas it doesn't exist.  `List<GeoPoint> polygon =  new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(T);` just tells that it should take this much size in memory. If you don't mention capacity,  the internal array will have to be repeatedly reallocated as the list grows.

Use this:

```
polygon.add( v_add(waypoints.get(i), M))
```

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB You know the size beforehand and you want to insert to specific indices. So use an Array. But mind that it will leave index 0 = null since you start with i=1.

Comment: @Fildor Check `UPDATE1`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use index inserting on the new ArrayList. Internally ArrayList uses array which dynamically grow based on it's length. So use add(Object) instead.